# Incrementing a progress bar value with a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

I am trying to create a download button, which when clicked, displays a progress bar whose value is initially set to 0. And increases the value every 3s.

This is my code.

```
function download () {
    let x = 0
    let increase = setInterval(() => { 
        document.getElementsByTagName('progress').value = x + 10;
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: And? Doesn't it work?

Comment: And yet, the progress bar has no real use since it will constantly lie about the download's progress state.

Comment: You never increase `x`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should add `max` attribute to your `<progress>` tag. Second, the issue with your code is that `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of elements, but you only want to get the first one:

```js
function download () {
    let x = 0;
    const el = document.getElementsByTagName('progress')[0];

    // `max` does access a number value whereas
    // `getAttribute` accesses a string value.
    const { max } = el;

    let increase = setInterval(() => { 
        el.value = x += 10;
        if (x >= max) {
          clearInterval(increase);
        }
    }, 100);
}

download();
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

Also, as [Peter Seliger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627243/peter-seliger) noted, you only need to query the element once outside of the interval. You can also clear the interval once the value has exceeded the max.

Comment: You should probably initialise the element value to zero first or you'll get that glitch.

Comment: @MichaelM. ... shouldn't `el` get queried exactly once within the function body of `download` instead with every interval again and again? And how about clearing the interval once the maximum value has been reached or gets exceeded?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Good catch! I've updated my answer. I think that'll make the code a bit faster.